# Button won't start another activity

Tags: android

My button with the id radio, to start second activity, isn't working and my app keeps crashing. The second button however starts another activity which is empty for the moment. Can somebody please tell me what did I miss, so my app stops crashing when I press the button.

my first activity xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mitja.radiohead.PrvaStran">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayou                   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.mitja.radiohead.PrvaStran">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="49dp"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slika"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="218dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:src="@drawable/radio"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/radio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="radio"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="323dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/predvajalnik"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="predvajalnik"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="371dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

java code of the first activity

```
    public class PrvaStran extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prva_stran);

        onClickButton();
        onClickButton2();
    }

    public void onClickButton()
    {
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radio);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent openMainAct = new Intent(PrvaStran.this, Radio.class);
                startActivity(openMainAct);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClickButton2()
    {
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.predvajalnik);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.mitja.radiohead.Predvajalnik");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

and the android manifestxml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mitja.radiohead">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".PrvaStran">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Radio"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.mitja.radiohead.Radio" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Predvajalnik">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.mitja.radiohead.Predvajalnik" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

what am I missing here? The second activity is made from a tutorial I saw on YouTube to create a listview with images and texts. I got the code from this site now I'm trying to use it in this app for practice. I haven't had any experience with Android Studio before so I'm asking for a little guide.

Comment: forgot to post a link with the code i use for the second activity on wich the button is suposed to open

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42771902/i-am-trying-to-implement-a-custom-listview-using-arrayadapter-but-all-the-items

Comment: Could you post crash log?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title. Because Android Studio has nothing to do with your problem. Android Studio is an _IDE_ and Android is a _Platform_

Comment: where can i find the crash log is it the log cat or?

Comment: Yes, it'll be red text in Logcat if using Android Studio 3.0 or Android Monitor if using 2.x

Comment: ok took me a while but i found it. it says 05-28 15:40:43.243 12955-12961/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe

Comment: That's not the error. Please edit your post to include the logcat in full

Comment: That's not the error. Please edit your post to include the logcat in full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are referencing same button to two different ids

```
private Button btn1;
 btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radio);
 btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.predvajalnik);
```

That is why app is getting crashed.
declare two different buttons and then refer them to respected ids.

```
private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;
 btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radio);
 btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.predvajalnik);
```

Comment: sory that the response took so long. used your advice and it worked thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: Great! you can accept this answer . Best of luck for rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the buttons as fields, but you do need to actually set both buttons listeners

```
findViewById(R.id.radio).setOnClickListener(
   ... 
);
findViewById(R.id.predvajalnik).setOnClickListener(
   ... 
);
```